# using the colorbox plugin with jQuery JS works locally but not from server

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I know I've over looked something, but as that statement suggests I can't figure out what it is.  I have downloaded the  latest jquery and colorbox libraries.  I've added this to a working a web page on my local PC  where I want to add javascript popups and have it running fine.  I'm using the colorbox for informational popups for a mapped area image.  Locally every thing works fine, but when I upload all the parts to my internet server all clicks are ignored. Now I've checked the permissions and relative locations of the style sheets and Js libraries and all matches the rest of the working parts.  The webpage in question is
 [here.](http://www.sowardssystemsconsulting.com/accounttracker/helppages/detailedview.html)    Several areas "search Bar" and "Add New" are programmed in.  They should work, but don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a FEW Errors, first off, to see what i'm seeing (i'll post the errors in a minute), trying opening your page in Google Chrome, and press Ctrl+Shift+J to open the debug console.

> **First Error**

```
//  Line 27 of detailedview.html
//  Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
settings = "width=900, height=320, top=20, left=20, scrollbars=yes, location=no, 
           directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, toolbar=no, resizable=no, dependent=no";
//  2 possible issues here;
    //  1.) Your "string" is on 2 lines, try closing first line and puttin '+ "' on second line
    //  2.) variable not declared, try full rewrite as follows:
var settings = "width=900, height=320, top=20, left=20, scrollbars=yes, location=no, "
    + "directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, toolbar=no, resizable=no, dependent=no";
```

> **Second & Third Error**

```
//  GET http://www.sowardssystemsconsulting.com/accounttracker/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js 403 (Forbidden) 
//  GET http://www.sowardssystemsconsulting.com/accounttracker/js/jquery.colorbox.js 403 (Forbidden) 
//  This is a permissions error on your server
//  Try ensuring the folder where your js is has correct access permissions 
//  In filezilla, this may require right clicking the folder and setting the file permissions
//  Or your hosting site may have account manager tools with some kind of "Reset File Permissions" button.
```

> **Last Error**

```
//  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 
//  If your fix the 2nd error, then this one will be corrected by default
```

Comment: That's odd the permissions on the js folder has not changed and there are other javascripts in there being used by the website namely the menu.  I tend to be a bit strict on permissions.  I didn't give read just execute and for my menu js it worked fine, but the jQuery and colorbox .js files needed read for every body.   Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, its pretty typical when setting up a new server. Just something to keep in mind for the future. FYI, I had tried it from two different systems on two different networks when i got those errors. And like i said, once the jQuery has permissions, the $ error will correct itself.

Comment: One more thing, just checked your link again and i still get error at the line `win = window.open('detaillrg.html', 'Closeup', 'width=1300, height=640, top=10, left=20, `, you should really one-line that or at least close the quotes and use concatenation.